# Python deleting 'stationary' data from array

Tags: python, numpy

If I collect some experimental data and load this into Python, what is the most efficient method of deleting the 'stationary' data? The following is a graphical example of what I have. I want to delete the elements of the `z` array where the gradient is almost 0 (i.e. approx. the first 60 elements).

Then I would be left with a noisy sine curve to later analyse.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,5,60)

z = np.zeros(120)
z[0:60] = 1e-2*x + 10
z[60:120] = np.sin(x) + 0.1*np.random.randn(len(x)) + 10

# plt.figure()
# plt.plot(z)
# plt.show()
```

**Edit**:
Tried paradiso's solution: `z = z[ np.gradient(z) > 1E-1 ]`

Similar results for setting `> 1e-2`, `> 1e-5`, etc.

Raw data:

[image: before]

After implementing solution:

[image: after]

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use numpy to compute the gradient explicitly (it just uses a central difference scheme) and then use numpy's boolean indexing feature (aka index arrays) to filter out indices with small values of the derivative:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.zeros(120)
z[0:60] = 1e-2*x + 10
z[60:120] = np.sin(x) + 0.1*np.random.randn(len(x)) + 10

z = z[ np.gradient(z) > 1E-1 ]
```

EDIT:

I'm a little confused by the failure demonstrated above - I wasn't able to reproduce it. However, you could make the filter a little more robust by adding the constraint that you only filter out data near the mean:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,5,60)

z = np.zeros(120)
z[0:60] = 1e-2*x + 10
z[60:120] = np.sin(x) + 0.1*np.random.randn(len(x)) + 10

# Take some markers of the data - first and second derivatives should     be plenty to filter out flat signals
z0 = np.mean(z)
dz = np.gradient(z)
ddz = np.gradient(dz)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)

# Plot the original signal
plt.plot(z)
plt.xticks([ 30*i for i in range(5) ])

thresh = 1E-3
# First try filtering on the 1st derivative
bool_result = np.abs(dz) > thresh

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.plot(z0+bool_result)
plt.plot(z[bool_result])
plt.yticks([]); plt.xticks([ 30*i for i in range(5) ])

# Now try filtering on both the first and proximity to the mean
bool_result = np.logical_not(np.logical_and(np.abs(dz) < thresh, np.abs(z-np.mean(z)) < .2))

plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.plot(z0+bool_result)
plt.plot(z[bool_result])
plt.yticks([]); plt.xticks([ 30*i for i in range(5) ])
plt.savefig("FilterResults.png")
```

Here are the filter results (the blue curves show the filter in the latter two images):
[image: Filter results]

Comment: I have several batches of data. Can the "small values of derivative" be small with respect to the sin curve? e.g. if I had `0.01*np.sin(x)` and also `27*np.sin(x)` for different batches and the `1e-2*x + 10` part remains approx. the same, how to deal with this?